# Sentences What for/For What need

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, construction

Both sentences sound right? And do they have a different meaning?

> For what needs life?

or

> What is life for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Both sentences sound right? And do they have a different meaning?**

I presume you mean

**Do** both sentences sound right? And do they have a different meaning?

Item 1 Sounds wrong and is wrong. **For what needs life?**

Item 2 is good. **What is life for?**

The definition of ;

> **needs** plural noun US; the things you must have for a satisfactory life:[Link C.E.D.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/needs)

I can only make a guess at what you are trying to say, so, as item 1 is wrong I cannot compare them.